# Will vs Would in this context

Tags: meaning, word-order

if I ask someone to tell me something in the future if there’s a problem.

They answer: “of course I would tell you”

The would is throwing me. Wouldn’t, “of course  I will tell you”more correct? Since would is past tense, referring or meaning they have no intent to speak up?

Comment: How did you phrase your question?

Comment: Hi there! I said “if in the future, or at any time if there is a problem that comes up please tell me”

Comment: Are you asking if there is some hidden meaning with "would"?

Comment: Hi Cascabel, I am just getting thrown off since would is generally used as past tense and not future tense in this case wouldn’t “will” be more appropriate?

Comment: Hello, Kelly. I almost missed your comment because  you need to ping me with a @ before my name. "Will" is not actually a "future tense" as you are thinking. "Would" is not necessarily a "past tense". Perhaps they meant the _irrealis_, such as "I would tell you if I knew"? You see, the context is very important. We do not really talk about tenses in English...more construction and usage.

Comment: This "would" would be almost equal with "may" or "might" IMO.

Answer (score 1):

While "would" was originally the past tense of "will", it has largely lost its sense of referring to the past. It is now used to discuss conditional and/or counterfactual situation. In your example, "I will tell you" expresses an unconditional intention to do so, while "I would tell you" expresses the idea that one will not necessarily do so: if there is no problem, there is nothing to tell. Telling is conditioned on there being a problem, so "would" is appropriate.

Comment: That’s not right.  In the context of the question, asking whether they would do something in a particular circumstance, the answer presupposes a circumstance in which the protasis is fulfilled.  “Yes <sc. if there is a problem> I will/would.

Comment: Thank you @Tuffy that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to understand 'would' (perhaps even three).

1. It can be the modal form used for will in the apodosis of a remote (or 'unfulfilled' or counterfactual conditional, conveying that the protasis is either untrue or unlikely.

> If it were raining, I would be wearing a mac.

2. It can be the continuous past of the copula (to be)

> When I lived in the country, I would walk through the woods to school.

3. But it can also be used to as what in Latin is called a 'generic subjunctive'.  "I  would always help a stranger in need."  This is different from "I **will** always help a stranger in need", which is a resolution for the future.

I should say that your sentence is the third '*generic* type.  That is, it is not the same as 'will' in this context.  But it does not mean that I am am saying that I am the *sort of person* to tell you if there is a problem.  Rather, it seems to me to be saying something about how the reply reflects the relationship between the two people:  perhaps the strength of their friendship.  "Of course I would:  we are friends, aren't we?"  But, If I am right, that one word, in its context and in its modal form, conveys all that.